# regexp return year and/or ranges from string

Tags: regex

I am trying to extract the following from a set of strings:

```
string1: copyright © 2014 domain.com. All rights reserved.
string2: copyright © 2012 - 2014 domain.net. All rights reserved.
string3: copyright © 2012 - 2014 domain. All rights reserved.
```

my reg exp to get year(or year range) after © and the domain:

```
\©([0-9]*)(.*?)(\.com|.net|.org|.co)

However it is returning
"","2014 domain.com"
"","2012 - 2014 domain.net"
null

I am expecting this:
"2014", "domain.com"
"2012 - 2014", "domain.net"
"2012 - 2014", "domain"
```

I am very new to regexp, any help or direction would be much appreciated.

Thanks,

Comment: i could tell you the answer but instead i'll help you fix the problem yourself. Use this and play with it. http://regex101.com/ - That way you can see yourself when your regex is too vague

Comment: For now, resolved. Thank you everyone for your input and direction.
(©|copyright) ([0-9]{4}(?: - [0-9]+)?) (.*?)(?=\.)

http://regex101.com/r/fZ6vW1/4

It may not cover all scenarios, but i am sure I have enough to go on to modify and update as needed. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This would capture the year or year range and the domain names into two separate groups,

```
([0-9]{4}(?: - [0-9]+)?) (.*?)(?=\. )
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/rH9jU8/1)

Answer (score 1):

I think Avinash's solution is good but i'd rather do

```
([0-9]{4}(?: - [0-9]+)?) (.*?)(?=\. All)
```

which would also catch this:

```
string4: copyright © 2012 - 2014 sub.domain.net. All rights reserved.
```

Comment: Both answers handle that string the same way. Put it into Avinash's linked demo and you'll see.

Comment: Both great. the other possibilities are that sometimes domain may just be a name such as "domain, inc". And sometimes All does not always follow this string.  ex: string5: copyright © 1998 - 2014 domain, Inc.

Comment: [This](http://regex101.com/r/rU5xB9/1) is Avinash's regex with your string4. Please tell me how that doesn't match.

Comment: my bad. clicked on my link and removed "All" including the space. You're right

Answer (score 0):

You can use this regex with matched group #1 (year range) and #2 (domain name):

```
/© *(\d{4}(?: *- *\d{4})?) *(\S+?(?:\.(?:com|net|org|co))?)(?=\.)/
```

#### [Online Regex Demo](http://regex101.com/r/fZ6vW1/2)